# Select all values from one table, check another table to see related columns and fetch more values

Tags: mysql

I really dont know how to phrase my question, probably why google is not giving me results that i need, but am going to try. 

I have two tables, required_files table and submitted_files table. I have a page where i want to display to a user all required files for submission and show which files he/she has submitted.

Required files table is as follows:

```
file_id     file_name                   mandatory
1         Registration Certificate          0
2         KRA Clearance                     1
3         3 Months Tax returns              0
4         Business Permit                   1
5         Tour Permit                       1
6         Country Govt Operating License    0
7         Certificate of good Conduct       0
```

file_id is unique, mandatory column is binary value to state whether the file is mandatory before registration or not. 

submitted files table is a follows

```
file_id    user_id     file_required_id    original_file_name  file_name_on_server                      submission_date
1             2             2                KRA_Form.docx      0a10f5291e9bcb6a345ac7a8f5705b8a.docx   2016-11-01
2             2             3               Tax_returns.docx    9f04361013df7e25235a03c506f347ed.docx   2016-11-03
3             3             3               Taxes.docx          86aea74cc87fb669510d9d4c488cbcf8.docx   2016-11-04
```

file_id is unique AI value, user_id col is unique value of the current user logged in, file_required_id column is related to files_required.file_id column 
 
When fetching the values i already have a user_id (in this case, lets use user_id = 2) Now i want to fetch all values of files_required table and check on files submitted table for files that user_id = 2 meaning user has submitted the files.

 
my sql query is as follows

```
SELECT files_required.*, submitted_files.* FROM submitted_files
RIGHT JOIN files_required ON  files_required.id = submitted_files.file_required_id
WHERE submitted_files.user_id = 2
```

This gives me two rows only where the user_ids matched but i want the entire files_required table values and show which files the user has submitted. Someone Kindly assist.

In the meantime, i am fetching files_requied table first then looping through the other table using a php script to look for submitted files for the given user. it works but its not what i wanted and is cumbersome and a rookie move.

Comment: Instead of having `user_id` check in `where` clause, have in `right join` itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having `user_id` condition in `RIGHT JOIN` itself like below query

```
SELECT files_required.*, submitted_files.* 
FROM submitted_files
RIGHT JOIN files_required ON  files_required.id = submitted_files.file_required_id
 AND submitted_files.user_id = 2
```

Comment: Right join is the sister to left join.. whichever you use, so long as the query is well phrased the results are the same.. much like RHD and LHD cars. hehe

Answer (score 0):

You want this.

```
SELECT submitted_files.user_id, files_required.*, submitted_files.* 
FROM submitted_files
RIGHT JOIN files_required ON  files_required.id = 
submitted_files.file_required_id
```

Don't put the where condition on `userid` as it will filter out the data just for that user. You want all the records and user should also be seen. Just put the `user_id` in the select statement.

Comment: Nope, that query is fetching everything, i want to fetch all required files and also check whether the user has submitted the files or not

Comment: Your query will give only 2 records as you have mentioned the where condition user_id = 2. Use my query, put the user_id in the select statement. You will come to know which user is associated with which record.

Comment: Am sorry but unfortunately this is fetching all submitted files, i wanted to fetch files that only a specific user has submitted.

Comment: @FallAndLearn What buddy? I have understood his requirement properly and answered it correctly. But you down rated it. I am very SAD :-(

Comment: see column three, user_id = 3 ... i did not want that, only need user id 2. only one user's files